# Most elegant/efficient way to define functions using the same variables

Tags: function, common-lisp, redundancy, keyword-argument

I defined multiple functions using some variables, that would normally be calculated in more of them. So I use keyword-arguments, that calculate the needed values by default.

Example:

```
(defun f (a b &key (distance (distance a b))) (c a b distance))
(defun g (a b &key (distance (distance a b))) (if (< distance (r a b))
                                                (f a b :distance distance)))
(defun h (a b &key (distance (distance a b))) (d a b distance))
(defun i (a b &key (distance (distance a b))) (g a b :distance distance)
                                              (h a b :distance distance))
```

Every function should be able to be called alone without specifying the keyword-arguments.

But now I also have to define the calculation of the keyword-arguments in every function.

Is there a more elegant/efficient way to do things like this?
(I thought about lazy evaluation and dynamic programming)

Comment: Can you give an example how 'lazy evaluation' or 'dynamic programming' would help with your problem?

Comment: I am not sure, if this would help. If I had found a solution in this way, I wouldn't have asked. If I could write the functions normally, but they are only evaluated once when calling some functions, it would be more elegant I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `#=`:

```
(defun foo (a b &key #1=(distance (distance a b))) #|...|#)

(defun bar (a b &key #1#) #|... |#)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably have fallen into a macro. e.g.

```
 (defmacro def-distance-fun (name &body body)
     `(defun ,name (a b &key (distance (distance a b))) ,@body))

 (def-distance-fun foo
       … blah )
```

If the names of "a" and "b" are variable, you can get a bit fancier with supplying the variables' symbols to the macro, and the macro could easily
enough include bindings only to the keyword arguments you named; e.g.

```
  (when (member 'distance lambda-list)
      `(distance (distance ,(first lambda-list) ,(second lambda-list))))
```